# How to view user name by id in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have two table's one user and another classrooms. 
Here is my `user` model:

```
public function classroom()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\classroom');
}
```

And here is my `classroom's` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

When user create classroom then i store in classroom table `id`, `user_id`, `class_name`, `section`. I already view class data in my blade page. But i can't view user name who created the classroom data.
In my `view` page

```
 @foreach($classrooms as $classroom)
                <li><b>Class code--><i>{{$classroom->class_code}}</i></b></li>
                <li><b>Subject--><i>{{$classroom->class_name}}</i></b></li>
                <li><b>Section--><i>{{$classroom->section}}</i></b></li>
                <li><b>created by--><i> ????  </i></b></li>
             @endforeach
```

My `controller`

```
$classrooms=classroomModel::where('id',$id)->get();
$posts = Status::where('class_id' , $id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
return view::make('class',compact('posts','classrooms'));
```

If i want to view user name who was created classroom data then what will be the right code and where should i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller:

```
$classrooms=classroomModel::where('id',$id)->with('user')->first();
```

in your view:

```
$classrooms->user->name;
```

Comment: Not working. Now my error is SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.classroom_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`classroom_id` in (47))

Comment: where do you store the data about who created the classroom? if I understand you correctly you dont store that info so how you want to get it?

Comment: In my user table there is a primary key id. And the user id i put in my classroom table name user_id. Now i show my data form classroom table. In class table there only user_id but not name. The name is in user table. So how can i view user name in my view page.

Comment: so if classroom have only 1 user why you declare it as hasMany users? this is where your problem is. you need to change it to user hasMany classrooms, but classRoom belongsTo user

Comment: see one to many relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122348/discussion-between-shuvo-and-amir-bar).